# What is the normal behavior of '+CEREG' unsolicited messages?

Tags: at-command, lte

My server is receiving data from a Telit ME910C1 LTE Cat-M modem. The unit is placed on a vehicle in movement.

Sometimes the responses are received late, and when it does get the response on time, the cell-id changes.

Please help me narrow down this problem: **I need an explanation about the `+CEREG` messages attached in the code section below**.

```
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AD9C30F",8 T:(0:43:36)  // server delay starts now 
+CEREG: 1,"4C01","AE25C11",8 T:(0:47:36)
+CEREG: 1,"4C01","AE15E10",8 T:(0:49:58)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE2DA10",8 T:(0:50:13)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE2DAOF",8 T:(0:52:30)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1D010",8 T:(0:52:48)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE19611",8 T:(0:54:48)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1960F",8 T:(0:56:9) 
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE19610",8 T:(0:57:54)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE26611",8 T:(0:58:27)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE19610",8 T:(0:58:38)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE26610",8 T:(0:58:48)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1B411",8 T:(1:2:9)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1B40F",8 T:(1:3:47) 
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1B415",8 T:(1:4:23)
+CEREG: 0 T:(1:7:27)
+CEREG: 0 T:(1:7:51)
+CEREG: 2 T:(1:7:52)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AE1B415",8 T:(1:7:52) 
+CEREG: 2,1,"4CO3","AE1B415",8 T:(1:8:1)  // Server delay ends here
+CEREG: 2,1,"4CO3","AE1B415",8 T:(1:8:8)
+CEREG: 2,1,"4CO3","AE1B415",8 T:(1:10:0)
+CEREG: 1,"4CO3","AD9E712",8 T:(1:11:30)
```

My only idea is that there might not be good cell coverage. Could I be right?

Comment: It is not actually clear what you are asking. 1) What module are you using? 2) Is that the response of `+CEREG?` it seems different from the syntax I know. 3) what AT commands are you sending? 4) what kind of help are you _exactly_ asking for?

Comment: A telit module ME910C1, that is the natural response i get when driving with the unit. i am not sending it commands maybe that why the syntax does not look familiar. i am asking if everything looks normal with the responses i get.

Comment: Ok, that's a module I know very well. Can you wait til tomorrow or you need a response now? In any case, please, edit your question by copying and pasting as text the log you attached as an image (it's impossible to answer otherwise). Add also the relevant info you wrote me in the previous comment.

Comment: I've provided an answer. Feel free to upvote and accept it if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 6):

What you see in your log is a sequence of **URC** messages (Unsolicited Result Code: an asynchronous message triggered by a specific event).

This specific URC was enabled by means of command

```
AT+CEREG=<mode>
```

Where **mode** can have values 0 (URCs disabled) and 1/2/3 (configuring the different *verbosity* level).

From what I can see, your device is set to `+CEREG=3`.

The format of the URCs is the following

```
short format: +CEREG: <stat>
long format: +CEREG: <stat>[,[<tac>],[<ci>],[<AcT>]]
extended long format: +CEREG: <stat>[,[<tac>],[<ci>],[<AcT>][,<cause_type>,<reject_cause>]]
```

In particular, are very important the **stat** values. According to [ME910C1 AT guide](https://www.telit.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Telit_ME910C1_NE910C1_ML865C1_AT_Commands_Reference_Guide_r4.pdf) the ones relevant for us are:

- **0** : not registered, terminal is not currently searching a new operator to register to
- **1** : registered, home network
- **2** : not registered, but terminal is currently searching a new operator to register to

### What happens to you

1. Since you are driving, you see a lot of URCs with just a cell switches; *stat* value is always 1 (registered).
2. After that, something happened: *stat* switched to 0 (not registered) probably due to a very low coverage (a tunnel?).
3. You have to drive for a certain time period, but finally the status changes to 2 (scanning). It means that the device receives something again but need some time to register again.
4. The modem finally gets registered again, and the cell is changed (out of the tunnel?).